# Pah reference of a static file in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

Hello I cannot access this file, I am getting module not found error, I tried both the root and public folder, can please someone assist with that?

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
var file = require('public/test.png');
```

Comment: do you want to access this image inside your server, or make it accessible to the API?

Comment: @Kepotx I need to upload the file using firebase API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` is specific for nodejs modules, and can't be used for static files

`app.use(express.static('public'))` Make that public folder is now accessible through your API via yourpath/test.png

What you want is to load image, so you can use it inside a function, therefore, you should use `fs`

```
fs.readFile('public/test.png', function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err; // Fail if the file can't be read.
  //Do whatever you want with 'data'
});
```

Comment: Ok I agree, how can I access the file then?

Comment: @blvckasvp hope it answers your question now

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for the update, is there a way to use just the readFile part of it? Like without wrapping in a function? fs.readFile('public/test.png');

Answer (score 0):

`require` is a reserved word, intended to load other nodejs modules but not your website' static assets.

If you follow the steps in [the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), once you do `app.use(express.static('public'))` your app will automatically serve static files under your "public" folder.

If you need to load a file for some reason, take a look at the [`fs` module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Comment: I need tu upload the file to firebase